# Drop rows when two columns aren't equal in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a data.frame which was the result of a merge of two separate data.frames, I have multiple columns but am concerned about Area.x and Area.y coming from both dataframes.

In particular, I want to remove all the rows where the value in Area.x is different from the value in Area.y (Area is numeric).

So I tried this, but it seems it doesn't work :

```
mergeTest[!(mergeTest$`Area.x` != mergeTest$`Area.y`),]
```

EDIT : Sorry, I found the problem, the guys who gave me the databases of 1 000 00 rows made the Area.x in numeric and the Area.y in chr. So the test just wasn't working

Really sorry again

Comment: Are these `factor` columns?

Comment: `mergeTest[which(mergeTest$'Area.x' != mergeTest$'Area.y'),]`

Comment: No, they are numeric, I dunno if this answers your question

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly you can do this

```
df<-data.frame(a=1:5,b=5:1)
i<-which(!(df$a==df$b))
df<-df[i, ]
```

Comment: I don't know, I tried on your example, this is the thing I want and it works on your df. But my data is about 2 000 000 rows, and it just returns me the same table, and the i just consists in all the rows of the dataframe, whereas I checked and there are some rows unequal

Comment: This removed NAs for me but not rows where text did not match in the two columns